# How to print binary array as characters

Tags: c, arrays, printing, binary, character

I have an array that holds 28 ints which are all 1's and 0's. However, I need to print this information as 4 characters so how do I get each 7 bytes of data to become one bit in order to print.

Not sure this makes sense so I will illustrate what I need to:

Right now my array (in order) is this: 0101101111011101011000100010
But I need to somehow take those first 7 numbers (0101101) and print that out as Z and do that with the next 7, the next 7...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: Take your input `0101101`. If you left pad that by `0`, you get `00101101` = 0x2D = '-'. If you right pad that by `0`, you get `01011010` = 0x5A = 'Z'. That is counter intuitive. Is that what you really want, to pad a zero to the right?

Comment: @R Sahu Bits are to be interpreted in little endian, not big.

Comment: The first 2 groups of 7 looks like "Zw", but that last 2 groups are not "+Z".

Comment: @chux Is that a general practice? I would love to read up on that topic, if you have a reference handy.

Comment: @R Sahu  The bit endian-ness is conceptually separate from byte endian-ness.  Wiki has good endian data.  The post hints at [7-bit RS232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rs232) which is LSbit first.  Serial communication protocols defines which Bit endian-ness they use.  e. g. RIFD tends to be little endian.  But I see both big and little amongst various standards.  In the Endian Holy-war I'm a [Lilliputian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliputian#History_and_politics).

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be something along the lines you are looking for.

```
int to_int(int *bits) {
   int power = 2;
   int digit = 1;
   int value = 0;

   int i=0;
   for(i=0; i <= 6; i++) {
        if(bits[i] == 1) {
            value += digit;
        }
        digit *= power;
    }

    return value;
}  


int main() {
    int myArray[28] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
                    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                    0, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 1, 0};

    char theChars[5];
    theChars[0] = to_char(&myArray[0]);
    theChars[1] = to_char(&myArray[7]);
    theChars[2] = to_char(&myArray[14]);
    theChars[3] = to_char(&myArray[21]);
    theChars[4] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",&theChars[0]);
}
```

Also, I don't think your expected output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is always the stupid way:
Cycle through each 7 blocks.

```
int bytes=7;
for(int i=0; i++;i<4){
     double ASCII = 0;
     for(int j=0; i++;j<bytes){
     ASCII+=Math.pow(2, bytes-j-1)*array[i*bytes + j]
     }
     char c = (char) ASCII // you'll have some trouble with types here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input array is called `inputBits[]` Try something like this:

```
const int input_bit_count = 28;
char output[input_bit_count / 7];
int outIdx = 0;

// step through the bit stream converting bits to 7-bit characters
for( int inIdx = 0; inIdx < input_bit_count; ){
    // shift over and add the next bit to this character
    output[outIdx] <<= 1;
    if( inputBits[inIdx] != 0 ){
        output[outIdx] |= 1;
    }

    inIdx++;
    if( inIdx % 7 == 0)
        // after each 7 bits, increment to next output character
        outIdx++;
}

// done processing, now print it out
for( int chIdx = 0; chIdx < input_bit_count / 7; chIdx++ ){
    printf( "%c", output[chIdx] );
}
```

Comment: When I try that my output is: AMv3
My output is supposed to be: Zw+Z"

Comment: So then what have you tried? Perhaps if you post some code we can help you debug it. Also, I simply had the bit order backwards, so change the if statement to `if( inputBits[input_bit_count - inIdx - 1] != 0 )`.

Comment: 1) `output[]` is not initialized to 0, thus `output[outIdx] <<= 1;` is shifting random data. 2) I suspect the bits are little endian.  This solution assume big.